# Make the header sticky and reduce the size on page scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code in which I want the `header` to stick on page scroll and also reduce the header size. however I managed only the sticky header on scroll down. I want all this effect to get reverted when scrolling top. any solution ?

This is my code: (also [on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/ayGwn/1/))

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

  if (scroll >= 500) {
    $(".clearHeader").addClass("darkHeader");
  }
});
```

```css
.clearHeader {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: rgba(107, 107, 107, 0.66);
  position: fixed;
  top: 200;
  width: 100%;
}
.darkHeader {
  height: 100px;
}
.wrapper {
  height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<header class="clearHeader">
</header>

<div class="wrapper">
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Any code related to your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to follow some random link to help you. If the question doesn't make sense and can't be answered without the link, it's not appropriate for this site. Instead, put the [**minimum** complete example](/help/mcve) in the question.

Comment: I've converted your fiddle into a Stack Snippet (the `<>` button on the toolbar) for you, so now the content is in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these and see the magic

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll >= 500) {
        $(".clearHeader").addClass("darkHeader");
    }
    else{
        $(".clearHeader").removeClass("darkHeader");
    }
});

.clearHeader{
    height: 200px; 
    background-color: #333;
    position: fixed;
    top:200;
    width: 100%;
}
.darkHeader {
    height: 100px;
}
.wrapper {
    height:2000px;
}
```

for more, check out my fiddle : - http://jsfiddle.net/Jinukurian7/w9EgE/5/

Answer (score 4):

Just add an `else` that removes the class:

```
if (scroll >= 500) {
  $(".clearHeader").addClass("darkHeader");
} else {                                           // <=== New
  $(".clearHeader").removeClass("darkHeader");     // <=== bit
}
```

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

  if (scroll >= 500) {
    $(".clearHeader").addClass("darkHeader");
  } else {
    $(".clearHeader").removeClass("darkHeader");
  }
});
```

```css
.clearHeader {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: rgba(107, 107, 107, 0.66);
  position: fixed;
  top: 200;
  width: 100%;
}
.darkHeader {
  height: 100px;
}
.wrapper {
  height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<header class="clearHeader">
</header>

<div class="wrapper">
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**However**, as the `scroll` event happens a **lot** as the user scrolls, it may be appropriate to reduce the amount of work we do on scroll by maintaining a flag:

```js
// Scoping function to avoid creating a global
(function() {
  var haveDarkHeader = false;
  
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var wantDarkHeader = $(window).scrollTop() >= 500;
    
    if (wantDarkHeader != haveDarkHeader) {
      haveDarkHeader = wantDarkHeader;
      $(".clearHeader").toggleClass("darkHeader", haveDarkHeader);
    }
  });
})();
```

```css
.clearHeader {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: rgba(107, 107, 107, 0.66);
  position: fixed;
  top: 200;
  width: 100%;
}
.darkHeader {
  height: 100px;
}
.wrapper {
  height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<header class="clearHeader">
</header>

<div class="wrapper">
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

It's more code, though, and duplicated state (we have the flag both in our JavaScript code and in the fact that the element does or doesn't have the class).

Answer (score 1):

Use [**`toggleClass()`**](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) to add or remove the class based on the scroll position:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  $(".clearHeader").toggleClass("darkHeader", scroll >= 500);
});
```

If `scroll` is greater or equal to 500, the darkHeader class will be applied.  Otherwise, it will be removed.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {    
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  $(".clearHeader").toggleClass("darkHeader", scroll >= 500);
});
```

```css
.clearHeader {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: rgba(107, 107, 107, 0.66);
  position: fixed;
  top: 200;
  width: 100%;
}
.darkHeader {
  height: 100px;
}
.wrapper {
  height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<header class="clearHeader">
</header>

<div class="wrapper">
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Indeed, `toggleClass` is cleaner if we're going to do it every time (as the OP and I did).